# CSS3 3D Transition changes firefox page size on hover

Tags: firefox, css, css-transitions, css-transforms

I am creating a 'bookshelf' which contains books that use a CSS3 transform to rotateY onHover.

My problem is that after a few hovers, the page will resize and become much longer. I am only experiencing this problem in Firefox 12.0.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/49KQk/

```
<div id="most-checked-out-books">

    <div class="f1_container">
        <div class="f1_card">
            <div class="book front face">
                <img src="books/new/harryPotter1.png" alt="Harry Potter (series)" />
            </div>
            <div class="back face center">
                <em>Harry Potter (series)</em>
                <br /><hr />
                By: J.K. Rowling
                <br /><hr />
                Checked Out <b>425</b> Times
                <br /><hr />
                <a href="#" title="Find 'Harry Potter' in PolyCat"><i class="icon-share-alt"></i><br />Find in PolyCAT</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> <!-- END CONTAINER -->

    <div class="f1_container">
        <div class="f1_card">
            <div class="book front face">
                <img src="books/new/ofMiceAndMen.png" alt="Of Mice and Men" />
            </div>
            <div class="back face center">
                <em>Of Mice and Men</em>
                <br /><hr />
                By: John Steinbeck
                <br /><hr />
                Checked Out <b>201</b> Times
                <br /><hr />
                <a href="#" title="Find 'Of Mice and Men' in PolyCat"><i class="icon-share-alt"></i><br />Find in PolyCAT</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> <!-- END CONTAINER -->         

</div><!-- END MCO BOOKS -->
```

CSS

```
.f1_container {
    height: 214px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 140px;
    z-index: 1;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 13px 9px 13px;
}


.f1_container {
    -moz-perspective: 1000px;
    -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
    -o-perspective: 1000px;
}

.f1_card {

    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s linear 0s;


    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s linear 0s;

    -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s linear 0s;

    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transition: all 0.5s linear 0s;

    height: 214px;
    width: 140px;
}

.f1_container:hover .f1_card, .f1_container.hover_effect #f1_card {
    -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.f1_container:hover .face.back {
    visibility: visible\9;
    height: 214px\9;
    width: 155px\9;
}

.face {
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;

    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;

    background-color: blue;
}

.face.back {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);

    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);

    -o-box-sizing: border-box;
    -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);

    box-sizing: border-box;
    transform: rotateY(180deg);

    background-color: white;
    padding-top: 5px;
    color: #333;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: "MyriadProRegular", sans-serif;

    /* IE HACK */
    visibility: hidden\9;
}

.back hr {
    width: 50%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.back i {
    font-size: 25px;    
}

.back a {
    font-size: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.back a:visited {
    color: blue;
}

.book {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.book img {
    height: 214px;
    width: 140px;
}
```

You can see after just one or two hovers the entire page resizes and the scrollbar gets smaller. Any ideas how to fix this bug?

Glen

Comment: I've played with 3D transforms quite a bit, and haven't seen this issue. I've just tried your code in Firefox 14 (the current version), and though the frame rate is rubbish in comparison to webkit, this issue didn't occur. As Firefox now auto updates, perhaps this isn't a big issue.

Comment: Alternatively, it might be that your graphics card isn't well supported by Firefox – if it's an older one, that they may be the problem.